¿Como cargar mi autocargador personalizado y el autocargador de vendor en php?
estoy desarrollando un proyecto usando php y composer, he creado mi propio autoloader para cargar las clases de mi aplicacion. Estuve intentando cargar mi autocargador y el autocargador de vendor en uno de mis archivos, de la siguiente manera:

el problema es que al momento de querer usar algunas de las clases de mi propio autocontrolador obtengo el siguiente resultado:
Clase 'setasign\FpdiPdfParser\PdfParser\PdfParser' no encontrada.
asi es como tengo actualmente mi autocargador:
<?php

class AutoCargador
{
    public static function registrar()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            $rutaBase = __DIR__; // Obtiene la ruta actual
            $rutaApp = $rutaBase . '/app';

            $rutaModelo = $rutaApp . '/model/' . $class . '.php'; // Ruta del modelo
            $rutaDao = $rutaApp . '/dao/' . $class . '.php'; // Ruta del dao
            $rutaBd = $rutaApp . '/config/' . $class . '.php'; // Ruta de la bd
            $rutaController = $rutaApp . '/controller/' . $class . '.php'; // Ruta del controller
            $rutaUtils = $rutaApp . '/utils/' . $class . '.php'; // Ruta de utils
            $rutaAPI = $rutaApp . '/controller/api/' . $class . '.php'; // Ruta de API

            // Verifica y carga el archivo de clase
            if (file_exists($rutaModelo)) {
                require_once $rutaModelo;
            } elseif (file_exists($rutaDao)) {
                require_once $rutaDao;
            } elseif (file_exists($rutaBd)) {
                require_once $rutaBd;
            } elseif (file_exists($rutaController)) {
                require_once $rutaController;
            } elseif (file_exists($rutaUtils)) {
                require_once $rutaUtils;
            } elseif (file_exists($rutaAPI)) {
                require_once $rutaAPI;
            } else {
                # Maneja el error
                throw new Exception("Clase '$class' no encontrada.");
            }
        });
    }
}

?>

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.
